# Why only 50 related tags?

Tags: support, tags, stack-exchange, api, related-tags

I'm using the Stack Exchange API and I want to get related tags of a particular tag. Fortunately, the API provides such an endpoint (`/2.3/tags/devops/related?pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow`).

Although, this only returns the **50 most common tags**, is there a way to get more tags? If not, is there somewhere an explanation on how Stack Exchange have chosen to return the top 50 tags, but not more/less (e.g., did you consider any criteria)?

Comment: If it is limited to the top 50 then I'm sure it is done for performance reasons.

Comment: I assume the related tags in what is shown in the sidebar on the tag page: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/devops/info. It doesn't look like it will be beneficial on that page if 200 tags were returned

Comment: Maybe a SEDE query is better suited: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1582345

Comment: Ah I see, the query selects all of the tags that were paired with the original tag (i.e., devops) at least once, right?

Comment: Yeah, 200 doesn't sound beneficial, but I was more interested in the reasoning behind the choice of 50 tags.

Comment: Yeah, I assume that that is how "related" is defined but maybe there are more criteria at play.  As for the 50: in general, if something is limited, specially in [list of things]  type of scenario's your best bet is performance. Things often break on Stack Overflow due to the sheer size of things. When it comes to tags there also is a component called tag-engine that is optimized for speed with an in-memory store. If those 50 tags come from that component then limited/reduce memory storage could be a reason as well.